Create stroke around transparent image
I want to create a die-cut sticker design. In my app, user should be able to upload any png file with transparent background. App should create double border around the image, to look like a die-cut sticker.
I tried to use dilate but result was not good enough. I decided to remove alpha from the image to make the edge detection easier, but final result is still not good enough.
Image with removed alpha: https://i.imgur.com/lXwC8y0.png
Here is a result:

I expect border like this (I just draw it myself to show die-cut effect):

Stroke should be smooth, to create easy to print die-cut image (it consumes image with removed alpha).
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/process-image', methods=['POST'])
def process_image():
    data = request.get_json()
    if not data or 'image' not in data:
        return 'No image provided', 400

    # Decode the base64 image to numpy array
    image_data = base64.b64decode(data['image'])
    image_array = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image_array, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Convert image to binary using Otsu's thresholding
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Draw contours on a blank canvas
    output_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.drawContours(output_image, contours, -1, (255), thickness=2)

    # Smooth the contours
    for contour in contours:
        epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
        cv2.polylines(output_image, [approx], isClosed=True, color=(255), thickness=3)

    _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', output_image)
    response_image = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')

    return jsonify({'image': response_image})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)


Would morphological operations work (e.g. dilate)?

Bad results, removing alpha and finding edges is better, but still not as I expect (example on the image)

Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66756081/7750891
